Understanding the Shoah
Good morning,
I am Italian (Catholic) and passionate about religions at a “non-professional amateur” level.
May I ask two questions (hoping they are not stupid):
(a) Can hatred of Jews also stem from the fact that it is God's chosen people? The envy of other religions as a push against Jews?
(b) Can the Shoah (extermination of Jews) have been God's demand to get to the Promised Land (present-day Israel)? Shoah as a necessary (political, human, social, geopolitical) price to get to Israel?
Thank you very much if you answer me. I repeat I am not a theologian or refined scholar but I have the hobby of studying religions.
Cordially,
Dr. Simone Nespolo

Weelcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for this question. For your a), you write "also". What other reasons have you heard?

Read Leviticus 26 and Deuteronomy 28.

Thank you for your question.
As Al Berko mentioned in his response, the subject of Holocaust has been a difficult topic for many Jewish people. I am myself a grandson of survivors and the subject of the World War 2 as well as reserch related to Holocaust interests me greatly. In response to your questions, as I understand, there could be several ways to explain what happened. It was a combination of many bad odds against the Jewish people, that perhaps each one is worthy to learn from and seek alleviating that it will not happen.
(a) Hatred of the Jewish people. Rabbi Eliezer Berkovitz discussed the subject in his book "Faith after the Holocaust". He analyzes religious hatred instigated historically in Christian Europe as well more recent era ethnic hatred in secularized societies were the legal system is not G-d given which allowed such a grave crime to take place. In my opinion, his best idea is demonstration that a perpetrator of crime has stronger hatred towards the victim than the victim has towards the perpetrator of crime because the victim always stays a loud witness in the human court and the Heavenly court. One can view chosenness of Jews due to our survival as a sequence of generations recording history, as a perpetual witness. Thus, R. Berkovits' suggests that Holocaust was such an attempt to erase the witness of the past without thinking that one will nevertheless stand for trial in the Heavenly Court of Justice.
(b) The internal Jewish answer as to why we got Holocaust. It has been also discussed in many ways, including the already mentioned book by R. Berkovits. Another book "Shoah" by Rabbi Yoel Schwartz and Rabbi Yitzchak Goldstein has a large section "Why the Holocaust?" - Searching for a Meaning presents several additional possible angles:

Birth Pangs of Redemption (big disasters preceed great religious events)
Search for Sins (lack of proper religious observance in years preceeding the war)
Assimilation and decline
Secular Zionism

These are not reasons but angles under which the causes of Holocaust could be discussed. We do not understand the Divine Justice. Especially Justice of such magnitude. We can only develop practical lessons for the life that we are given ahead of us. There are a number of other books and articles on the subject.
At the same time, it is important to note that Hitler's regime in Germany had a strong affinity to that of the Stalin's regime in the USSR. They celebrated the same holidays (like May 1st), had red color flags, and were leaders of "workers movements". The marxist ideology, by declaring ends justify means, has destroyed lives of hundreds of millions of people. Stalin also planned massive repressions against Jewish people in 1953, but his death on the Jewish holiday Purim put an end to his evil plans.

The only cause of antisemitism is stated at the very beginning of the Torah, in the story of the patriarch Isaac, the first person born Jewish:

Then Isaac sowed in that land, and reaped in the same year a hundredfold; and the Lord blessed him. And the man became rich, and gained more and more, until he became very wealthy.  He had possessions of flocks, and possessions of herds, and large numbers of servants. And the Philistines envied him.  And the Philistines stopped up all the wells which his father's servants had dug, in the days of Abraham his father, and filled them with earth. And Abimelech [king of the Philistines] said to Isaac, “Go away from us, because you are much mightier than we are.” And Isaac departed from there, and encamped in the valley of Gerar, and dwelt there. [Genesis 26:12-17]

So, to summarize, Isaac lives peacefully among his neighbors, then, through hard and honest work, becomes fabulously wealthy and powerful.  So his neighbors hate him, harm him by depriving him of water, and finally expel him.
The only reason for antisemitism is jealousy.  The envy of those who are perceived as more successful, more prosperous, more intelligent, God's chosen. Antisemites never acknowledge this reason because it makes them look bad, and Jews don't publicize it for fear of exacerbating antisemitism.  That’s why you don’t hear much about it.

First, religions do not explain phenomena per se, they interpret them. While religious language commonly masquerades as explanations, we should remember that those are mere personal imaginations and speculations of the authors, not some God-attested truths.
Regarding your questions:

Yes, it is true, e.g the Midrash (Shemot_Rabbah.2.4, last sentence) interprets the name of Mt. Sinai (סיני) as phonetically similar to Sin'a (שנאה) hatred, to propose that the anti-semitism of the gentiles nations was incepted at the legendary Mt. Sinai revelation.
AFAIK, there's no "envy of other religions", each religion considers itself to be the true one.

The Holocaust  - the horrific extermination of millions of innocent Jews, is a very controversial topic and is NOT discussed readily in religious circles. Some see it as a punishment for centuries of European secularization, and some as the beginning of the "Messianic era".
However, many Zionist groups, both observant and not, do see the Holocaust posteriorly as essential in the process of the establishment of the Jewish State.


I remind you, that in the Jewish tradition, all historical phenomena are attributed teleologically to God's will to promote the coming of the Messia, and the "World to Come" as His "final solution", so to speak.
